# Set Google Calendar Reminder - Migrate from API v2 to API v3

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api

Previously, I have the following workable Google Calendar API 2

### Google Calendar API v2

```
    CalendarEventEntry calendarEventEntry = new CalendarEventEntry();
    calendarEventEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct(message));
    calendarEventEntry.setContent(new PlainTextConstruct(message));
    calendarEventEntry.addTime(when);

    // 0 minute reminder
    Reminder reminder = new Reminder();
    reminder.setMinutes(0);
    reminder.setMethod(Method.SMS);
    List<Reminder> reminders = calendarEventEntry.getReminder();
    reminders.add(reminder);

    // Send the request and receive the response:
    try {
        calendarEventEntry = calendarService.insert(postUrl, calendarEventEntry);
    } catch(IOException exp) {
        log.error(null, exp);
        return false;
    } catch (ServiceException exp) {
        log.error(null, exp);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
```

### Now, I want to migrate to Google Calendar API v3

```
    // Create a new event.
    Event event = new Event();
    event.setSummary(message);
    event.setStart(startEventDateTime);
    event.setEnd(endEventDateTime);

    // 0 minute reminder
    EventReminder reminder = new EventReminder();
    reminder.setMinutes(0);
    reminder.setMethod("sms");

    List<EventReminder> listEventReminder = new ArrayList<EventReminder>();
    listEventReminder.add(reminder);

    System.out.println("Is null? = " + event.getReminders());

    event.getReminders().setOverrides(listEventReminder);

    try {
        Event createdEvent = service.events().insert(calendarListEntry.getId(), event).execute();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log.error(null, ex);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```

However, `event.getReminders` will always return null. I was wondering, what is the correct way to do so?

In case you're interested, I place the complete code set at GitHub : [GoogleCalendar.java](https://github.com/yccheok/jstock/blob/master/src/org/yccheok/jstock/alert/GoogleCalendar.java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just by looking at the API, have you tried this?

```
Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders();
reminders.setUseDefault(false);
List<EventReminder> listEventReminder = new ArrayList<EventReminder>();
listEventReminder.add(reminder);
reminders.setOverrides(listEventReminder);
event.setReminders(reminders);

System.out.println("Is null? = " + event.getReminders());
```

Comment: Thanks! Going to try it out and update on the status.

Comment: Bravo! It works! The trick is, we need to set `setUseDefault` to false. I edited your answer slightly.

Comment: need to call setUseDefault(false) twice? :)

Comment: Opps. I missed out that line while copying the code. Revert back.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of API 3 (rev85=1.18-rc)  Reminders are only accepted for PRIMARY calendar. Setting reminders for other calendars is ignored - you get the default. 
No error message, no documentation.