# Unable to add reminders to Google Calendar event

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I am able to create events programmatically which are added to my Google Calendar (API v3) fine, but none of these events have reminders on them. I have followed the answers on [other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444238/set-google-calendar-reminder-migrate-from-api-v2-to-api-v3) and my reminder code looks like the following:

```
Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
    .setUseDefault(false)
    .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(
        new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(60),
        new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10)));
```

I have tried with `setUseDefault(true)` in place of the overrides and I still see nothing in the notifications section.

I tried adding `setSendNotifications(true)` but that hasn't been of any help adding the reminders themselves.

It might be worth noting that the account associated with this calendar uses an email that is not hosted through Google.

Comment: Have you set the `event.setReminders(reminders);` at the end of the code? Here is a sample code for [creating a event with reminders](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events#metadata). I hope it helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot: Yes, I've more-or-less copied that over.

Comment: What do you mean by "It might be worth noting that the account associated with this calendar uses an email that is not hosted through Google." ? Are you trying to set reminders for a guest who does not have google account? Reminders are always attached to the logged in user and no one else.

Comment: @luc I am also not able to add reminder for event using service account.